# How do I specify Float 80 (size 10) from Float 128 (size 16) in Mac OS X with Clang?

Tags: c, macos, floating-point, clang, primitive

I'm working on a library that tries to implement an extended C standard in a cross-platform way, using various default compilers for that purpose. I've hit a hurdle when handling extended precision *vs.* quadruple precision on Mac OS X.

GCC-family compilers have macros `__float80` and `__float128` which handle this for me nicely, but the default Mac OS X clang compiler does not seem to have an equivalent.

Version info:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Additionally, some testing leads me to understand `long double` and `1.0L` both default to Float 128 (size 16) on Mac. I know Float 80 is x86 defined, and Swift seems to support Float 80 extended precision, so there must be a way to handle them on Mac. I've searched a good deal and can't find how, though. Any help or links are appreciated.

Comment: More important than the size of `long double` (which may be padded) are the `LDBL_...` constants from `<float.h>`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I checked the LDBL_MAX value, it's `1.18973149535723176502e+4932L`, which seems consistent with Float 80 encoding. This is strange indeed.

Comment: I guess my question now becomes: is there a built-in for float128 on Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program shown below prints this Apple Clang 11.0.0 on macOS 10.14.6:

```
The long double format:
    has 64 base-2 digits in its significand, and
    has normal exponents from -16382 (inclusive) to 16384 (exclusive).
```

This indicates it is using the Intel 80-bit format for `long double`. The fact that `sizeof` shows it to be 16 bytes merely indicates the 80 bits (ten bytes) are kept in 16 byte containers for convenience of alignment and whatnot.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("The long double format:\n");
    printf("\thas %d base-%d digits in its significand, and\n",
        LDBL_MANT_DIG, FLT_RADIX);
    printf("\thas normal exponents from %d (inclusive) to %d (exclusive).\n",
        LDBL_MIN_EXP-1, LDBL_MAX_EXP);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps confirm what I seemed to understand by following the advice given to me in the comments of the question. However, this still leaves the question of the existence of a built-in implementation of float128 on Mac, or whether I should default to float80. Do you know if float128 exists on Mac ?

Comment: @TristanDuquesne: I do not believe Apple’s compiler currently supports a 128-bit floating-point type, although I have not specifically checked. Many years ago, they supported a type that was two `double` objects, one with high bits and one with low bits, but they were a kludge, not following IEEE-754 semantics.

Comment: Alright, you answered my question. I'll wait a day or so to see if someone can provide an authoritative source on whether float128 is implemented on the Apple clang compiler, but if not, I'll set your answer as correct. Feel free to edit what you've said in the comments into your answer if you think it's important for posterity. Many thanks!